# When are WASD keys implemented in my code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am coding a C# script for a player, which uses the WASD keys to move around. My script is below.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rigid;
    public float horizontal;
    public float vertical;
    public float rate = 30.5f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0.0f, vertical);
        rigid.AddForce(direction * rate);
    }
}
```

There is nothing wrong with my code at all, however, I just would like to know how the WASD keys have *already* been implemented. Could someone explain this to be?

Comment: Check the Input Manager for what values are assigned to "Horizontal" and "Vertical"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity's Inputs are controlled over the **[Input Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html)** (Edit --> Project Settings, then select the Input category).

**The Input Manager uses the following types of controls:**

1. **Key** refers to any key on a physical keyboard, such as W, Shift, or
   the space bar.
   Button refers to any button on a physical controller (for example, gamepads), such as the X button on an Xbox One
   controller

```cs
Input.GetKey("Jump") {...};
```

2. A **virtual axis** (plural: axes) is mapped to a control, such as a
   button or a key. When the user activates the control, the axis receives a value in
   the range of [-1..1]. You can use this value in your scripts

```cs
horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
```

Your line of code, refers to an **Axis** defined in the Input Manager with the Name "Horizontal". This Axis itself implements Positive Buttons as well as Negative Buttons. In this case A/D, which you then are able to indirectly get the input from in your code.